# Updating/Intercepting HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, query-string

Here's a wierd one. I'm reusing a code base that unfortunately must not be updated. This code makes a call to `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`. Ideally, I need to push a value into this collection with every request that is made. Is this possible - perhaps in an HTTP Module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using reflection, the simplest way to do it would be to use the RewritePath function on the current HttpContext object in order to modify the querystring.

Using an [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx), it might look something like:

```
context.RewritePath(context.Request.Path, context.Request.PathInfo, newQueryStringHere!);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ditto Espo's answer and I would like to add that usually in medium trust (specific to many shared hostings) you will not have access to reflection so ... RewritePath will remain your probably only choice.